# Webhook Payload explanation

Tags: azure-devops

Looking at both the documentation and example service hooks there is little to no explanation about what the contents of the payload is.

For example, I create a Release Started and a Release Completed Service hook, and when I look at the payload none of the included guids actually represent the id of the release pipeline that triggered the alert.

Here is an obfuscated payload I receive:

```
{
    "subscriptionId": "000-000-000-000-000",
    "notificationId": 12,
    "id": "000-000-000-000-000",
    "eventType": "ms.vss-release.deployment-started-event",
    "publisherId": "rm",
    "message": {
        "text": "Deployment of release Release-430 to stage Test started.",
        "html": "Deployment on stage <a href='https://TESTAcentral.visualstudio.com/TESTA/_release?_a=environment-summary&definitionId=34&definitionEnvironmentId=12'>Test</a> started.",
        "markdown": "Deployment on stage [Test](https://TESTAcentral.visualstudio.com/TESTA/_release?_a=environment-summary&definitionId=34&definitionEnvironmentId=12) started."
    },
    "detailedMessage": {
        "text": "Deployment of release Release-430 on stage Test started.\r\nTrigger: After successful deployment of Dev",
        "html": "Deployment on stage <a href='https://TESTAcentral.visualstudio.com/TESTA/_release?_a=environment-summary&definitionId=34&definitionEnvironmentId=12'>Test</a> started.<br>Trigger: After successful deployment of Dev",
        "markdown": "Deployment on stage [Test](https://TESTAcentral.visualstudio.com/TESTA/_release?_a=environment-summary&definitionId=34&definitionEnvironmentId=12) started.\r\nTrigger: After successful deployment of Dev"
    },
    "resourceVersion": null,
    "resourceContainers": {
        "collection": {
            "id": "000-000-000-000-000",
            "baseUrl": "https://TESTAcentral.vsrm.visualstudio.com/"
        },
        "account": {
            "id": "000-000-000-000-000",
            "baseUrl": "https://TESTAcentral.vsrm.visualstudio.com/"
        },
        "project": {
            "id": "000-000-000-000-000",
            "baseUrl": "https://TESTAcentral.vsrm.visualstudio.com/"
        }
    },
    "createdDate": "2020-01-29T13:49:01.1293269Z",
    "resource": null
}
```

How should I identify the pipeline that actually triggered this webhook?

Please dont tell me that the intention is to parse the markdown or html fields and break apart that url. The utility of this entire process is compromised if you dont include the triggering identifier!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**

This is a issue which may caused by new UI in Service Hook.

The temporarily workaround is turn off "Service Hooks setting page improvements preview" in Preview Feature

[image]

Comment: I did select All, and it does not contain the information prescribed in the the example. In fact I have had to open a ticket about it:

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/900507/azuredevops-service-hooks-not-saving-all-values.html

Comment: I'd appreciate you giving it an upvote so we can get this fixed

Comment: @Wjdavis5 Thanks for your kindly response. In the meantime, this setting still works if you do change it from the old UI. If you disable the **Service Hooks setting page improvements preview**. Seems this issue related to the preview new UI. After I enabled the new UI, I could reproduce the issue. Have also upvoted the ticket you filed in above developer community link.